# Generating graph from a batch of adjacency matrices

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I am trying to train a network for generating adjacency matrix for graphs. In the training process, for a single graph I use

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np

adj = np.asarray([[0,1,0,0],[1,0,1,0],[0,0,0,1], [0,0,1,0]])   

G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(adj)
```

for transforming adjacency to graph. However, while training the network, I need to do this with a batch of matrices and it seems that `networkx` cannot do this. Is there a package that can handle the following:

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np

adjs = []
adjs.append(np.asarray([[0,1,0,0],[1,0,1,0],[0,0,0,1], [0,0,1,0]]))
adjs.append(np.asarray([[0,1,0,1],[1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1], [1,0,1,0]]))

adjs = np.asarray(adjs)    

G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(adjs)
```

Comment: Should `G` be a single graph or a list of graphs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `map` over the `nx.from_numpy_matrix` function to apply it over all the adjacency matrices in the `adjs` list. Something like this

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np

adjs = []
adjs.append(np.asarray([[0,1,0,0],[1,0,1,0],[0,0,0,1], [0,0,1,0]]))
adjs.append(np.asarray([[0,1,0,1],[1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1], [1,0,1,0]]))

adjs = np.asarray(adjs)    

graph_list = list(map(lambda adj_matrix:nx.from_numpy_matrix(adj_matrix), adjs))
```

Now, `graph_list` is simply a list of NetworkX graphs.

```
for graph in graph_list:
    print("Printing information for Graph at index:", idx)
    print(graph.nodes())
    print(graph.edges())

# Output:
# Printing information for Graph at index: 0
# [0, 1, 2, 3]
# [(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3)]
# Printing information for Graph at index: 1
# [0, 1, 2, 3]
# [(0, 1), (0, 3), (2, 3)]
```

You can view the code [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Gzy6VzNFpIpJpWaxYNxsRrffNnLFCGke) as well.

Reference:

- [Python Map Tutorial](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html)